# Uniswap PoolAddress.sol error: `TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "uint160"`

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat, uniswap

This is [Uniswap PoolAddress library repo](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/libraries/PoolAddress.sol)

this code is throwing error while I was working on a hardhat project:

```
function computeAddress(address factory, PoolKey memory key) internal pure returns (address pool) {
        require(key.token0 < key.token1);

        //*******************this is causing the error***************
        pool = address(
            uint160(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        hex'ff',
                        factory,
                        keccak256(abi.encode(key.token0, key.token1, key.fee)),
                        POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

I copied the full code on Remix and I get an error for the `pool=address` line: 'TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes32" to "uint160".'

I read the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#address):

> Explicit conversions to and from address are allowed for uint160,
> integer literals, bytes20 and contract types.

it also has a warning and I do not understand what it means:

> If you convert a type that uses a larger byte size to an address, for
> example bytes32, then the address is truncated. To reduce conversion
> ambiguity, starting with version 0.4.24, the compiler will force you
> to make the truncation explicit in the conversion. Take for example
> the 32-byte value
> 0x111122223333444455556666777788889999AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFCCCC.
>
> You can use address(uint160(bytes20(b))), which results in
> 0x111122223333444455556666777788889999aAaa, or you can use
> address(uint160(uint256(b))), which results in
> 0x777788889999AaAAbBbbCcccddDdeeeEfFFfCcCc.

Since docs mentions that I can convert from bytes20 to int160, I tried this and the error message has gone:

```
function computeAddress(address factory, PoolKey memory key) internal pure returns (address pool) {
        require(key.token0 < key.token1);
        pool = address(

            uint160(
                bytes20(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        hex'ff',
                        factory,
                        keccak256(abi.encode(key.token0, key.token1, key.fee)),
                        POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH
                    )
                )
            )
            )
        );
    }
```

But I do not think that converting from `bytes32` to `bytes20` is a valid approach because it will remove some of the hex values in `bytes32`.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [hardhat.config.ts](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/hardhat.config.ts) of the repo and this is the settings that have implemented:

```
const DEFAULT_COMPILER_SETTINGS = {
  version: '0.7.6',
  settings: {
    evmVersion: 'istanbul',
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 1_000_000,
    },
    metadata: {
      bytecodeHash: 'none',
    },
  },
}
```

Then applied those in

```
solidity: {
    compilers: [DEFAULT_COMPILER_SETTINGS],
    ...
}
```